# Solve N system equations with N unknowns in Python

Tags: python

I have a portfolio that has N assets (N>300), I have weight and price of each asset and my goal is to back out share(quantity) of each asset. To simplify, lets say N=3 for illustration purpose.

---

Background:

Some basics of portfolio here to better understand the context:
You can think of portfolio as a basket, in this basket, I have three items (assets) Apple, Orange and Banana. I know the price and quantity (shares) of each item and I can calculate the holding percentage (weight) of each item, for example:

```
price=[50,30,20]
quantity=[20,30,30]
```

```
Eg:Holding percentage (weight) of Apple: 50*20/(50*20+30*30+20*30)=0.4
```

so by same logic:

`weight=[0.4,0.36,0.24]`

---

Questions:

For some reason, I want to remove Apple from my basket, so the new weight would be:

`weight_new=[0,0.6,0.4]`

This is because once I remove the Apple, I will rescale Orange and Banana:

```
new weight of Orange: 0.36/(0.36+0,24)=0.6
new weight of Banana: 0.24/(0.36+0.24)=0.4
```

My desired output is UPDATED quantity by using weight_updated and price, so my formal question is :

```
weight_updated=[0,0.6,0.4]
price=[50,30,20]
```

I want to solve for the equations:

```
50*x1 / (50*x1 + 30*x2 + 20*x3)=0
30*x2 / (50*x1 + 30*x2 + 20*x3)=0.6
20*x3 / (50*x1 + 30*x2 + 20*x3)=0.4
```

As there might be infinite solutions:

`solution x1=0, x2=x3`

Is this problem solvable? Is there a way to force some additional constraints to solve for the actual UPDATED quantity? For example, can I use original quantity [20,30,30] to set up some boundaries for new ones as I expect the UPDATED quantity should be anchoring on original quantity.

Noticed that I'd like a general solution to this question as I have 300 or more assets in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like we are missing a key piece of information, which is the actual sum, so we can only really calculate the ratio of x1 to x2 to x3, but that's probably enough to get you where you want to go.

You want a generalized solution, so I took a look at the math you showed and it seems pretty easy to generalize, so I rearranged yielding the following where the first line is your equation, and the last line is general, ready to be applied to generate the matrix:
[image: Equations]

Now that we have that equation, we just need to plug it into a matrix and turn `numpy` loose on it as you suggested. To fit yours, you need only change `tot` to whatever your total is and `sol2` will show real values instead of the ratios.

```
import numpy as np

weight = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]
price = [40, 60, 90]
# share = [x1, x2, x3]

A = np.array(price) * np.expand_dims(np.array(weight), 1) - np.diag(price)
b = np.ones(shape=[len(weight)], dtype=float)
sol = np.linalg.solve(A, b)

tot = 100.0
raw_sum = sum(np.multiply(sol, price))
sol2 = sol * tot / raw_sum

print(sol)
print(sol2)
print(tot, sum(np.multiply(sol2, price)))
```

Running that yields

```
[-5.69986828e+14 -2.53327479e+14 -4.22212465e+14]
[0.75       0.33333333 0.55555556]
100.0 100.0
```

Which makes sense with the sample numbers we are using.

Let me know if you have any questions.

- EDIT - simplified the code with @cards' recommendations.

Comment: could you explain me why you need to compute `sol2`? Is part of the problem or just to make the solution more "understandable" (in a new scale)?

Comment: @cards I offered the computation for `sol2` because its likely he wants the actual values, not just a random smattering of ratios. In your solution the total sum is 100.9, which is kind of an unusual amount. In order to get the actual values from your solution he will have to perform the same operation on your `sol` anyways, it's just not shown in your answer. I do like how you calculated the matrix `A` in yours, its much cleaner than mine. Thanks for the question!

Comment: Ok, now I got it. You are applying a rescaling of the basis vectors which describe the kernel of the transformation. This is possible because the system is homogenous:) By the way `numpy.array`s support vector operations: `sol2 = sol * tot / raw_sum`

Comment: you could do the scalar product also with `x@y`, `np.multiply(x, y).sum()`, `np.dot(x, y)`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and discussions! I realized that the example I have is not supposed to have unique solution. My intention was to just provide an example, sorry for the confusion. Another follow up is that there is no constraint on my total shares for this specific question, but it is good to have the flexibility to rescale it to be 100.  I have one final question: why b is np.ones? I thought it is a 0 array? (As your general equation shows, the RHS is 0?)

Comment: @Derek With a linear system like that and without the true total, it will generally just settle on 0 for each value, which satisfies the system (0 + 0 + ... + 0 = 0, no matter how many equations we use), but doesn't meet our expectations. By giving some constant non-zero value it converges on the ratios we are interested in. If you have the actual total, it can be subbed into one of the rows (and setting `b` to 0 otherwise) to give actual values.

Comment: I see. So my context is I have 300 securities and I know the weight and price, I want to back out shares for each security, so I do NOT have a sum constraint. Does that mean I can only solve for the ratios of securities without the actual shares? Initially, I thought I can get weight if given price and shares, so I can always solve for third unknown (shares) by these other two (price and weight).

Comment: @Derek I'm sorry, I don't understand this comment well enough to answer. I am not familiar with the terms securities, shares, etc. If you have an additional equation or constraint in terms of the variables in my short "proof" or try to explain it differently for me then I would be glad to take a look at it and see if the code can be updated to reflect that

Comment: Hi I edit the question, hope it makes sense. I understand that my original question can only ends up with ratios of no further constraint added. If I have a sum constraint like x1+x2+x3=100, I can add it to the system as a new equation and solve for exact values. However, I only have some boundaries of x1, x2 and x3. Please see the edited one for more info and let me know if anything still blurs. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to use properly `np.linalg.solve` so I found a way to compute the kernel of the matrix representation of the system which corresponds to the solution of the linear *homogeneous* system of equations.

See answer of *BitsAreNumbersToo* for mathematical details.

```
import numpy as np


def null(A, atol=1e-13, rtol=0):
    # find solution of the homogeneous system
    # from https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RankNullspace.html
    A = np.atleast_2d(A)
    _, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A)
    tol = max(atol, rtol * s[0])
    nnz = (s >= tol).sum()
    ns = vh[nnz:].conj().T
    return ns.flatten()


# data
p = np.array([40,60,90], dtype=float)
w = np.array([0.3, 0.2, 0.5], dtype=float)

# size of the system
n = p.size

# set the linear homogenous system 
W = np.expand_dims(w, 1)

# broadcast p
A = p*W - np.diag(p)

# solve it
sol = null(A)
print(sol)

# check solution
is_sol = np.allclose(np.dot(A, sol), np.zeros(n))
print(is_sol)
```

Output

```
[0.756745   0.33633111 0.56055185]
True
```

Comment: the solution space is closed under scalar multiplication, hence any multiple of `sol` will be again a solution, for ex make the solution `sol` a unitary vector `u_sol = sol / np.linalg.norm(sol)` where  the scalar is the reciprocal of the norm is the stretch factor

Comment: another possibility could be a _relative_ vector `sol / np.abs(sol).min()` -> `[2.25       1.         1.66666667]`

Answer (score 0):

The question as posed is meaningless. There's an infinite number of answers since the problem is under-constrained. You can for example choose any value for `x1` and still satisfy the constraints:

```py
import numpy as np

weight = np.array((0.3, 0.2, 0.5))
price = np.array((40, 60, 90))
x1_literally_anything = 999

a = np.vstack((
    np.diag(price) - np.outer(weight, price),
    (1, 0, 0),
))
x, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(
    a=a, b=(0, 0, 0, x1_literally_anything), rcond=None,
)

print('x =', x)
print('price*x/(price.x) =', price*x / price.dot(x))
```

```
x = [999. 444. 740.]
price*x/(price.x) = [0.3 0.2 0.5]
```